# Prestashop 1.7 order details page not loading templates from layout

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop-1.7

I'm using Prestashop 1.7.2.4. I installed a module called Universal Payment Module which is not entirely compatible with Prestashop 1.7.

https://github.com/prestalab/universalpay/tree/ps17

After I select this payment option and I click on "Order with an obligation to pay" I go to the order details page but the page is loaded with unformatted text. Besides, I cannot see any other templates like the header or the footer. After inspecting elements there are no errors in the console, and I don't see anything in the head tag.

Finally, after some tests and comparisons with other modules, I fixed it by adding these codes to the file called payment_execution.tpl:

```
{extends file='page.tpl'}
{block name="content"}
{/block}
```

This is the whole file called payment_execution.tpl:

```
{extends file='page.tpl'} {* added *}
{capture name=path}{$paysistem->name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}{/capture}
{block name="content"} {* added *}

    <h1 class="page-heading">
        {l s='Order summary' mod='universalpay'}
    </h1>

    {if $nbProducts <= 0}
        <p class="alert alert-warning">
            {l s='Your shopping cart is empty.' mod='universalpay'}
        </p>
    {else}
        <form action="{$link->getModuleLink('universalpay', 'validation', [], true)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" method="post">
            <div class="box cheque-box">
                <h3 class="page-subheading">
                    {$paysistem->name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}
                </h3>
                <p class="cheque-indent">
                    {$paysistem->description nofilter}
                </p>
                <p>
                    <b>{l s='Please confirm your order by clicking "I confirm my order"' mod='universalpay'}.</b>
                </p>
            </div>
            <p class="cart_navigation clearfix" id="cart_navigation">
                <a class="button-exclusive btn btn-default"
                   href="{$link->getPageLink('order', true, NULL, "step=3")|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}">
                    <i class="icon-chevron-left"></i>{l s='Other payment methods' mod='universalpay'}
                </a>
                <input type="hidden" name="id_universalpay_system" value="{$paysistem->id|intval}"/>
                <button class="button btn btn-default button-medium" type="submit">
                    <span>{l s='I confirm my order' mod='universalpay'}<i class="icon-chevron-right right"></i></span>
                </button>
            </p>
        </form>
    {/if}

{/block} {* added *}
```

However, I'm not sure about the use of those codes and if that fix is completely acceptable.

Comment: If everything works correctly then the approach acceptable. In 1.7* templates, all view pages inherit the page.tpl file where all basic markup is done and if you want to use it you need to extend the file